# Opencart location to url field character limit

Tags: php, html, opencart

I have an opencart store (v1.5.1) and I have customized the location field in the opencart back end so that what is put in the feild is echoed to the add to cart button so I can link to products on amazon through amazon affiliates. But for some reason the links with amazon are really long and opencart only outputs about half of the link. So it is not tracking and I am not getting any commission.

This is what is outputted by opencart on the button. ([http://www.ekobikes.co.uk/?*route*=electric-scooters/eko-1000W-evo](http://www.ekobikes.co.uk/?_route_=electric-scooters/eko-1000W-evo))

```
<a id="button-cart" class="button" rel="nofollow" href="http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00CKLNURM/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&amp;camp=1634&amp;creative=6738&amp;creativeASIN=B00CKLNURM&amp;a"><span>Purchase NOW!</span></a>
```

And the full link is:
`http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00CKLNURM/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=B00CKLNURM&linkCode=as2&tag=ekobikes-21`

So not all of it is being outputted for some reason.

---

Next in the form to add the link to the product I have this. 
(`/admin/view/catalog/product_form.tpl`)

```
         <tr>
           <td><?php echo $entry_location; ?></td>
           <td><input type="text" name="location" maxlength="250" value="<?php echo $location; ?>" /></td>
         </tr>
```

I tried to set a max length and this works a little bit but for some reason when you save the form it shortens it automatically anyway.

For the button I have: (`/catalog/view/theme/default/product/product.tlp`)

```
<a id="button-cart" class="button" rel="nofollow" href="<?php echo $location; ?>"><span>Purchase NOW!</span></a>
```

So basically I would like to know if anyone has any ideas on what this could be, it is strange to me. I don't know why opencart would just cut of half of the links and if anyone knows how to make it to have 1000 characters or something like that so it outputs the whole link.

P.S - I have tried using a URL shortener but then amazon does not recognize the link. It has to be the exact one that is provided.

Comment: Most probably you have not enough character length in the DB. Probably you have a `VARCHAR(32)` which limits the inserted text to 32 characters only (the rest is stripped and thrown away). Your solution is to find that column and increase the length to something more satisfiable, e.g. to `VARCHAR(200)` or more if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Location is a `VARCHAR(128)` by default

Try running

```
ALTER TABLE product MODIFY location VARCHAR(1000)
```

(Or use phpMyAdmin to do this if more comfortable with a GUI)

Always worth backing up the data in your database before you start tweaking it if there is anything you don't want to lose.